# Parse large text document, to keep only "account number", and a specific keyword ("Market Value")

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I have a large textdocument (~20000 rows), The body of which looks something like this :

```
Invoice Account / Name: 
0234523454 / XYZCORPORATIONS
Charge Group
Portfolio Fee
Date
Our / Your Ref
Security / Category
Charge Item
No of Units
Market Value
Charge Amt Invoice Amt
30-Sep-2019
Debt Instruments
PORTFOLIO FEE
CS
USD 
USD 219.12 USD 219.12
14,136,666.31
 Invoice Account / Name: 
021346676343/ abcdefgcopr
M0919-031  / Page 3 of 35
Charge Group
Portfolio Fee
Date
Our / Your Re
Security / Category
Charge Item
No of Units
Market Value
Charge Amt Invoice Amt
30-Sep-2019
Equity Instruments
USD 788,640.00 USD 12.22
USD 12.22
PORTFOLIO FEE-
EC_CS
 Invoice Account / Name: 
123498761233/ somethingelsecorporation
Charge Group
Portfolio Fee
Date
Our / Your Ref
```

Blocks like this are repeated thousands of times. 
Attempting Output:

```
Invoice Account / Name: 
    0234523454 / XYZCORPORATIONS
Market Value
Invoice Account / Name: 
    021346676343/ abcdefgcopr
Market Value
Invoice Account / Name: 
    123498761233/ somethingelsecorporation
Market Value
```

As I have never attempted something like this before, I have two questions:
1. How to identify and keep a sentence like this :

```
Invoice Account / Name: 
0234523454 / XYZCORPORATIONS
```

Which has no fixed length?

1. How to keep only the keyword "Market value" other than this.

Is it wise to use nltk for this? Or can it be handled with regular expressions and string processing?

Comment: Are you wanting to store the actual market value, or just the text `Market Value`?

Comment: Just the text Market Value. I dont need any of the other number, other than the account number.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using only `regex`:

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    matches = re.findall('Invoice Account \/ Name:\n.*', f.read())

with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    [f.write(f'{m}\nMarket Value\n') for m in matches]
```

Output file:

```
Invoice Account / Name:
0234523454 / XYZCORPORATIONS
Market Value
Invoice Account / Name:
021346676343/ abcdefgcopr
Market Value
Invoice Account / Name:
123498761233/ somethingelsecorporation
Market Value
```

Comment: This will run much faster then my answer over a larger data set, +1

Comment: @Alderven ,  Thank you for solution so far. But this assumes that there is exactly one "Market Value" Keyword between each "Invoice account/ Name". However in txt file sometime there are multiple occurrences of "Market Value" between two account numbers

`Invoice Account / Name:
0234523454 / XYZCORPORATIONS
Market Value
MarketValue
Invoice Account / Name:
021346676343/ abcdefgcopr
Market Value
Invoice Account / Name:
123498761233/ somethingelsecorporation
Market Value
Market Value
Market Value
`

Apologies for not explaining this earlier, newbie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use string processing to search for and find what you're seeking.

```
result = []

with open('num.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = list(file.readlines())

    for indx, row in enumerate(data): 
        if 'Invoice Account' in row:

            accountnumber = data[indx+1].split('/')[0].strip() # Get account number from next line
            companyname = data[indx+1].split('/')[1].strip() # Get company name from next line

            # Store all results in a dictionary, you could print, store in other ways as well.

            info = {'Account Number': accountnumber,
                    'Company Name': companyname,
                    'Market Value': '',
                }

            # Append the dictionary to a list called result
            result.append(info)
```

Then you can access the data directly from each dictionary, which will only contain values for individual companies.

```
for data in result:
    print(f"""Account Name: {data['Company Name']}
Account Number: {data['Account Number']}
Market Value: {data['Market Value']}
""")
```

Output:

```
Account Name: XYZCORPORATIONS
Account Number: 0234523454
Market Value: 

Account Name: abcdefgcopr
Account Number: 021346676343
Market Value: 

Account Name: somethingelsecorporation
Account Number: 123498761233
Market Value:
```